# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused between two microservices via docker

Tags: java, docker, api, rest, microservices

I have two microservices. One named "configuration-service" and the other named "sender-service". The first one after REST makes it possible to download the configuration. Locally, using the (Intellij) environment, the services communicate without any problem. The problem comes when I try to download anything via rest from one service to another using Docker.
Moreover after running configuration-service, I can easily retrieve the value data in a browser.

However, when I run the following compose down, I get an error like in the title.
In the rest of the threads, all I found was a suggestion from 'network', but it doesn't work.

To sum up, the communication problem occurs only with the use of a docker, which eliminates the problem with the code.

First dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8888
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

second:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8889
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    configuration-service:
      image: configuration:latest
      container_name: configuration-service
      ports:
        - "8889:8889"
      restart: always
      networks:
      - common-network

    sender-service:
      image: sender:latest
      container_name: sender-service
      ports:
        - "8888:8888"     
      restart: always
      networks:
      - common-network
      

networks:
  common-network:
  driver: bridge
```

thanks in advance for any tip

Comment: Would be useful if you showed the actual stacktrace

Comment: "Locally, they communicate without problem" ... Well, are you using localhost? If so, then the problem **is** the code, because that wont work in docker

Answer (score 0):

I think @OneCricketeer has identified the issue.

If you run both containers (outside of Docker), you'd need to run them as `--net=host` or similar so that they both bind to host ports, so that one can access the other via `localhost:${PORT}`.

If you run the containers under Docker Compose, they won't be accessible as `localhost` but as `configuration-service` and `sender-service` respectively accessibly on `8889` and `8888` respectively (assuming the services indeed bind to these ports).

> **NOTE** the Compose `ports` functionality is only relevant to process bound to the host's network. From the host, you should be able to confirm access to these services on `8888` and `8889` because of the `ports` **but** this is unnecessary to ensure `configuration-service` and `sender-service` are able to communicate with one another.

Comment: so why I can use the localhost via browser, and the result is correct?

Comment: @kamilwilk because you added mapping between configuration-service localhost and your host in docker-compose by specifing  this `8889:8889`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you provide url like this to communicate with service which listens on port 8889:

`localhost:8889/path`

localhost means sth different in each container, try sth like this instead:

`configuration-service:8889/path`